# Unable to navigate to the URL in Microsoft Edge

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I'm trying to launch `Microsoft Edge` browser and navigate to `google.com`, but as soon as the browser launches the execution stops and the browser closes.

I'm getting the below error in the console.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10102
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xyz', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:96)
    at pageObjects.LaunchBrowser.browserUtility(LaunchBrowser.java:51)
    at execution.TestPrint.printJob(TestPrint.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10102
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
    ... 57 more
```

My System configuration is as below

> OS Build 18362.356
> Version 1903
> Edition Windows Pro

I have installed the latest Microsoft WebDriver - Release 17134.

Please find below my code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

My Microsoft Edge version is

> Microsoft Edge 44.18362.329.0
>
> Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting driver into projects directory? I don't think it's working fine when in c:/

Comment: I tried that as well it didn't work @MichalDobrzycki

Comment: Jainam is right you should try to downgrade the Edge Version. But I have still doubts whether this should working: [Issues with edge browser](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1090573/Not-able-to-run-javascript-through-selenium-on-edg) Could you please afterwards share your comment which version is working for your? Because we are also facing same issues.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted this question to the Microsoft queries and I got the below solution.

https://macops.ca/installing-webdriver-as-a-feature-on-demand-in-windows-redstone-5/

This link shows how to install a webdriver for the latest version.
I tried and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It works well with me.

From the error, It seems the issue is with version compatibility. 
Verify that version of MicrosoftEdgeBrowser is matching with the version of MicrosoftWebDriver.

For eg. If my MicrosoftEdgeBrowser is : "Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299"
then MicrosoftWebDriver's version should also be same (i.e. #16299), MicrosoftWebDriver's version should not be higher than Browsers version.

You can download matching version of MicrosoftWebDriver from below:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver

Comment: The Edge version which I have is as below

Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.329.0

In the above website which you mentioned I am unable to see the version 18 for MicrosoftWebDriver

Comment: I have also tried to install 
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

which they have mentioned in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Maybe Microsoft Edge version #18362 doesn't have supported Webdriver yet. For now, you can downgrade the Microsoft Edge version to (#17134 or #16299) and continue the work.